# ncftp not looking into .netrc

Tags: ncftp, .netrc

I have this sort of stanza in my `.netrc`:

```
machine ftp.mydomain.com
        login mylogin 
        password mypassword
```

and while I can successfully connect with `ftp`:

```
ftp ftp.mydomain.com
```

and passing credentials to `ncftp`:

```
ncftp -umylogin -pmypassword ftp.mydomain.com
```

I get this using only `ncftp ftp.mydomain.com`

```
NcFTP 3.2.4 (May 16, 2010) by Mike Gleason (http://www.NcFTP.com/contact/).
Connecting to xxx.xxx.0.140...                                                    
ProFTPD 1.3.1 Server (Debian) [::ffff:xxx.xxx.0.140]
Login incorrect.                                                                
Sleeping 20 seconds...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ncftp` does not use `.netrc` file for storing preferences, see `[man ncftp][1]` FILES section for details. Instead it uses `$HOME/.ncftp/` directory

Connect to your server and use `bookmark` command for creating a record in `$HOME/.ncftp/bookmarks` file

Comment: I relied on [this doc](http://www.minix-vmd.org/pub/Minix-vmd/1.7.0/wwwman/man1/ncftp.1.html) I found online but it was wrong... However the bookmarks facility forces using at least once in interactive mode, not always what you want... Thanks

Comment: This man is very old,  I guess. I could not find any mentions about netrc in [change log](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftpd/doc/whatsnew.html)

Answer (score 3):

This is rewrite of dchirikov's answer with links and a howto.

Although [old man pages](https://www.minix-vmd.org/pub/Minix-vmd/1.7.0/wwwman/man1/ncftp.1.html) seem to indicate it was once the case, It appears that ncftp has not supported the `.netrc` file for quite some time.  The [most recent, official man page](https://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/doc/ncftp.html) makes no mention of it.  I found a [debian bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=170064) from 2002 regarding the lack of support.  The ncftp developer (Mike Gleason) responded with:

> The `.netrc` file has little to do with ncftpput's config file, which can 
>   contain exactly one set of login information.  Proper parsing of a 
>   `.netrc` bloats the code without tangible benefit since you can't use it 
>   with ncftpput without editing it.

I think it's safe to say that `.netrc` support was intentionally removed and won't be returning anytime soon.

The ncftp way to achieve passwordless login/transfer is to make a bookmark.  It's pretty straightforward:

```
$ ncftp -u username ftp.example.com
[...]
Password requested by [host IP address] for user "username".

User username okay, need password.

Password:
```

Then you enter the password and you are in.  You should get the server's welcome text and:

```
Restricted user logged in.
Logged in to ftp.example.com.
```

At the `ncftp / >` prompt, enter `bookmark`.  You'll be prompted to give a name to the bookmark (the suggestion is a useful version of the host name, `example` in our example), and confirm that you want to save the password.

If you quit `ncftp` and browse the file `~/.ncftp/bookmarks`, you'll see a line for your host, with the bookmark name, the host name, the username, and the password.  The password is saved in an encoded form, which is probably not totally secure, but at least more secure than plaintext as it is in the `.netrc` file.

Now do:

```
$ ncftp example
[...]
Restricted user logged in.
Logged in to ftp.example.com.
ncftp / >
```

And there you are.  The bookmarks are good for the put/get versions of ncftp too.  For instance,

```
$ ncftpput example destdir file
```

Will put `file` on the server `ftp.example.com` in the directory `destdir`.

Comment: Your answer is a useful expansion of the accepted one. I followed the steps, but I find it still prompts for the password even though it does resolve the host and use the username from the bookmark file. The bookmark file does have the encoded password in it.

Comment: Hm. I found I had to `set save-passwords yes` for it to auto login completely. (Without resaving the bookmark). It defaults to `ask`. I'm using it inside a docker container, with the .ncftp folder mounted, so possibly some issue there. I've noticed the prompts don't display properly (they come late after pressing enter), so perhaps I missed the ask-to-save prompt...

Comment: @scipilot: Thanks for that extra info.  Feel free to edit the answer and put `set save-passwords yes` in the proper place.